# how to use Simple Injector to Azure Worker Role

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, simple-injector

I referenced several documents but I need correct implementation to do it correctly.

**References**

1. Unity to Worker Role: https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/building-windows-azure-services-without-compromising-testability/
2. SimpleInjector for Console app:  http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/consoleintegration.html

**My questions**

1. Reference-1, `Unity` use `using (var uc = new UnityContainer()){...}` but SimpleInjector has `ThreadScopedLifestyle` or `AsyncScopedLifestyle`. Which one do I use?
2. Reference-2 has `static Main` class, `static readonly Container`, and `static contructor`. Do I define `static Container` for Worker role? what about `static constructor` for dependency registration?
3. I implemented as below *My Implementation* section. Is this code implemented correctly?

**Reference Code**

Reference 1;

```
static class Program
{
    static readonly Container container;

    static Program()
    {
        container = new Container();

        container.Register<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>();
        container.Register<MyRootType>();

        container.Verify();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var service = container.GetInstance<MyRootType>();
        service.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Reference 2;

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
 public override void Run()
 {
     // This is a sample worker implementation. Replace with your logic.
     Trace.WriteLine("Worker entry point called", "Information");

     using (var uc = new UnityContainer())
     {
         uc.RegisterType<ILogger, TableStorageLogger>();
         uc.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IMessageHandler>, IMessageHandler[]>();

         var processor = uc.Resolve<MessageProcessor>();

         while (true)
         {
             processor.Process();
             Thread.Sleep(10000);
             Trace.WriteLine("Working", "Information");
         }
     }
 }
```

**My Implementation**

I thought (1) `Container` could be enough to be `static`, (2) `OnStart` is good place to register services, and (3) I intended service instances are created and disposed per each loop.

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    static readonly Container container = new Container();

    public override void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            using (ThreadScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
            {
                var service = container.GetInstance<SomeService>();
                service.DoSomething();
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool OnStart(){
        // define.
        container.Register<SomeService>();
        container.Register<ProcessRecorderSetting>();
        container.Verify();
    } 
}
```

Note: I don't know above code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reference-1, Unity use using (var uc = new UnityContainer()){...} but SimpleInjector has ThreadScopedLifestyle or AsyncScopedLifestyle. Which one do I use?

If I'm not mistaken, an Azure Worker Role is a short-lived application, that gets kicked off to do one simple thing and than dies quickly, just like you would with a Console Application.

Considering DI, this makes the development of a Worker Role very similar to that of a Console application. This means:

- The application is short-lived
- Will only run one request (compared to running multiple requests in parallel as happens with web services/applications)
- There is a limit set of dependencies that need to be registered.

What this means is that, since the application is single-threaded and short-lived, there is no need to use a scoped lifestyle (such as `ThreadScopedLifestyle` or `AsyncScopedLifestyle`). Instead you could easily register all dependencies as singleton, resolve the root, call its method, and dispose the container.

If however, your application lives for a long time, and goes on in an endless loop, you typically want to simulate the notion of a 'request'. This typically means that every loop is a request, and during that request you resolve from the container. Note that you only need a scoped lifestyle if you actually have scoped registrations. If not, you don't have to wrap the request in a scope. If you have scoped registrations, you'll have to wrap each request in a scope, just as you did in your example.

> Reference-2 has static Main class, static readonly Container, and static contructor. Do I define static Container for Worker role? what about static constructor for dependency registration?

Although static constructors give thread-safety and singleton behavior for free, they do however complicate debugging in case an exception is thrown, since the real error is wrapped in a `TypeInitializationException`. Your cctor however does make it easy to initialize your static `Container` field. It's fine to have the `Container` in a static field.

However, since these types of applications are really small with only a small set of Dependencies, do container to *not* use a DI Container *at all*. Instead use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). This might sound like a strange advice from someone who develops and maintains a DI Container, but I found it more practical to use Pure DI for small applications, especially when everything your register is singleton anyway. The advantages are:

- You have compile-time support over the construction of your object graph
- It prevents having to use a third party tool
- There is a lot of overhead with DI Containers when it comes to the application's initialization phase, while Worker Roles should start up quickly.
- Can be considerably easier for small object graphs.